# Clojure Library for Swing: externalized / runtime editable definition?

Tags: java, swing, clojure

There a few Java Libraries out there that let you define your UI layout (and/or actions) declaratively and at runtime (or at least at 'startup' of runtime) - usually using XML.

For instance:

- ['swixml'](https://github.com/swixml)
- ['compositor'](http://compositor.sourceforge.net)

I know that Clojure could just simply use these packages (in theory at least; I haven't tried); but I would like to do the declarative bits in Clojure itself, not XML.

I know of the popular Clojure library ['seesaw'](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw); which lets you do this - but as far as I can tell - it is designed to let you define the UI at design-time, rather than at runtime.

What I'm after - is a way to ship a runtime program (in a JAR/JARs say) ; but for it to read its UI layout definition at startup; thereby allowing a certain amount of customization to 'tweak' the UI separately from the main codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the seesaw code at runtime and execute it ? Or you could put a layer ontop of seesaw to load up definitions of your app, e.g. a map with `:main-panel monitor-panel` from an edn file and then render that at runtime.

I guess it depends how dynamic your UI needs to be at runtime.

Comment: So run an 'eval' on the 'code-as-configuraiton' bits maybe ?

Comment: (I'm still pretty basic when it comes to Clojure ; so I'm probably thinking about this the wrong way) ; but I think - even the example on the See-Saw Site , The "(invoke-later[...])" can just be provided with a map (as you say) - but I guess I can just load the text representation of that map from a text file...? (Or do I create a 'real' ".clj" file and 'require' it maybe) .... dunno.

Comment: (eval (load-edn "C:\\temp\\mydata.clj")) will do it I guess...but I should be careful about loading random code lying around of course.

Comment: You could eval or just use a data structure that you can read to configure the app. Eval could be risky depending on where you deploy the app to